# Operator norm bounds

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$m need to prove the following bounds:

\begin{align*}
||A|| &\leq \sqrt{m} \max_{i \in \{1, 2, \dots, m\}}  \big( \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2 \big)^{1/2}\\
||A|| &\geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{mn}} \sum_{i=1}^m | \sum_{j=1}^nA_{ij}|
\end{align*}

where $||A||$ is the operator norm $||A||=  max \{ ||Ax||_{l_2}: ||x||_{l_2}=1\}$

Attempt:
For the lower bound:
\begin{align*}
||A|| &= \max_{||x||=1} \{ \langle x, A^TAx \rangle \}
\end{align*}
cannot proceed beyond this

For the upper bound:

\begin{align*}
||Ax|| &= \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m\big(\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}x_j \big)^2} \\
&\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^m ( \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}^2) ( \sum_{k=1}^nx_k^2 )}\\
&\leq \sqrt{m}\max_{i \in \{1, 2, \dots, m\}}  \big( \sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}^2 \big)^{1/2}
\end{align*}

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @CheeHan Added.